# Can you resize images in a question?

Tags: support, editing, images

I asked [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18917/were-there-two-death-stars-in-construction-at-the-same-time/), but the images I used are rather large. Can you/how can you resize images in the question (short of downloading the image, resizing it on the computer, and re-uploading the question)?

Comment: You can use HTML

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This feature exists, it's documented in the [advanced help](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#images).

> You can also use standard HTML image syntax, which allows you to scale the width and height of the image.
>
> ```
> <img src="https://example.com/sample.png" width="100" height="100">
> ```

There's also a quick way of resizing images that have been uploaded to Stack Exchange's servers (or any imgur server, in fact). From [Resizing an image in a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25051/resizing-an-image-in-a-post/25052#25052): given an image URL like `https://i.stack.imgur.com/admM6.jpg`, add `s` or `m` or `l` before the `.jpg` (i.e. `https://i.stack.imgur.com/admM6s.jpg`, etc.) to scale down the image to a predefined size.

Original:
[image: raw]

`s`:
[image: small]

`m`:
[image: medium]

`l`:
[image: large]

Comment: It doesn't seem to work with .pgn with transparent parts.